# How to take multiple values from one column in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

Ok so the question maybe broad but I will try to explain as best as I can.

Basically I have a “tags” table and a “posts” table. As I am using eloquent, my posts table has a column named `tag_ig`. This column will basically enter the tags tables `id` in to the posts tables `tag_id`.

What I currently do not get is, how can I fetch the data?
Assuming this is my code:

```
$postsWithTags = Post::with(‘tags’)->get();
```

And now I could just use a foreach in my blade and get the column named `tag_id` data. But here is the thing. If my `tag_id` column had this data (1, 2, 3, 4), how can I fetch that data and display the actual tag name?

I have a tags table and a posts table. And I am using a single column in posts table named `tag_id` to store multiple tag id from tags table (this is a summary of what I just explained).

Is there any better ways to achieve this? Do I need to create a separate table? Or stick with this? And how can I take the multiple values from one column which data is something like this (1, 2, 3, 4) and also display the tag name.

**UPDATE**

Table structure:

```
Tags
 |_ id
 |_ name
 |_ deleted_at
 |_ created_at
 |_ updated_at

Posts
 |_ id
 |_ tag_id
 |_ title
 |_ content
 |_ deleted_at
 |_ created_at
 |_ updated_at
```

Comment: How does tags table row look like? Can you post your tables structure?

Comment: @Tpojka I have added the table structure and updated the question

Comment: As pointed, when having `tag_id` in `posts` table, you are limited to one tag per post. Wether your posts could have only one tag better approach is @Josh 's answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a many to many relationship. A post can have many tags and a tag can belong to many posts. You need to break this relationship with a pivot table.

post_tag |_ post_id |_ tag_id

Then on your `Post` object add the following method

```
function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

And you can now do

```
$postsWithTags = Post::with(‘tags’)->get();
```

Note: You no longer need the tag_id column in the posts table.

Below is the relationship before and after this change

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Making an intermediate table correct? But I am curious though. Can I take values (1, 2, 3, 4) in one column (maybe using json?)